# Bed occupancy at a specific time

Tags: oracle10g

How possibly can we find if a bed was empty or filled at a specific time stamp over a month. The information in table available is Bed no. Admission Date_time & Discharge date_time. Table is below

bed occupancy at 03:00 AM

Let us finetune our requirement a little. Suppose we have 100 beds in hospital IPD. Most of the time the beds remain occupied. What we want to know is that for how long any of the 100 beds remain vacant during 24 hours on a specified date.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; an English (not code) explanation of the logic to be implemented; and the expected output for that sample data. StackOverflow is not a service where we write **YOUR** homework for you; **YOU** need to attempt it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    BedNumber,
    CASE
        WHEN TO_TIMESTAMP(Admission_DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') <= TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
            AND (TO_TIMESTAMP(Discharge_DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') > TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                OR Discharge_DateTime IS NULL) THEN 'Filled'
        ELSE 'Empty'
    END AS BedStatus
FROM 
    YourTableName
WHERE 
    TO_TIMESTAMP(Admission_DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') -- Specify the start timestamp
    AND TO_TIMESTAMP(Admission_DateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < ADD_MONTHS(TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 1) -- Specify the end timestamp
```

Make sure to replace YourTableName with the actual name of your table. Adjust the 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' value to the specific timestamp you want to check for bed occupancy at 03:00 AM.

The query utilizes the TO_TIMESTAMP function to convert the date and time strings to Oracle's timestamp format. It then performs the necessary comparisons to determine the bed status at the specified timestamp. The ADD_MONTHS function is used to calculate the end timestamp as one month after the specified start timestamp.

Remember to modify the SQL query based on your specific table structure and requirements within Oracle 10g.

Comment: There are problems with this: `TO_TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` is not valid as `'YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00'` is not a valid date (you may have forgotten to replace `YYYY-MM-DD` with an actual date); using `TO_TIMESTAMP` on a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column is, at best, pointless and, at worst, will generate errors or incorrect data (you should just use the underlying `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column and not use `TO_TIMESTAMP`); and if there is no row for a specific day then your query will not show `Empty` it will have no data.

Comment: Dear ukgaudram,, Thank you very much for your time, however it didn't work. I tried different tricks but of no use..